# Sending a single reminder email for each address instead of multiple emails

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that sends email to remind people to get recertified.

The spreadsheet set up:
[image]

The script sends the person an email to their address if they are nearing expiration, or if their certification has already expired. This part works.

The real use-case spreadsheet (which I cannot share) has about 30 operators and 50 machines. Sending upwards of 15 emails to each person is inadvisable.

How do I send one email that lists all the equipment to be recertified on?

```vb
Sub AutoMailer()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("C4", "BZ50")
Dim R As Range
For Each R In RList
    If IsEmpty(R) = False Then
        If (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) >= 335 And (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) < 365 Then
            R.Interior.ColorIndex = 27 'Change color to yellow
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 2))
              
                .Subject = "You're due for retraining and certification"
                .Body = "Hello, " & R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 1)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                  & "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has almost expired. You have " & (365 - (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now))) & " days until it expires."
                .Display
            End With
        ElseIf (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) > 365 Then
            R.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Change color to red
            Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
            With EItem
                .To = R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 2))
                
                .Subject = "You're overdue for retraining and certification"
                .Body = "Hello, " & R.Offset(, -(R.Column - 1)) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                  & "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has expired. You are " & ((DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) - 365) & " days overdue for retraining."
                .Display
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there a way to, instead of looking at each cell, look by row, read which cells are out of date, and then construct one email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is a good one, create an outer loop to go through each name, and an inner loop to go through each equipment in that row.

Instead of creating a new email for each equipment, add each equipment to a variable. Then create your email at the end using the variable.

I've changed your code as little as possible. I've added an outer loop to loop through the names in column A, and a variable to check whether the subject should say due or overdue. It's difficult to test without recreating your worksheet, but give this a try:

```
Sub AutoMailer()
Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim EItem As Object
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("C4", "BZ50")
Dim R As Range
Dim sBody As String
Dim RNames As Range, RName As Range
Set RNames = Range("A4", "A50")
Dim sOverdue As String

'Loop through names
For Each RName In RNames
If IsEmpty(RName) = False Then

sOverdue = "due"
    
    'Loop through equipment in current row
    For Each R In Intersect(RList, RName.EntireRow)
        If IsEmpty(R) = False Then
            If (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) >= 335 And (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) < 365 Then
                R.Interior.ColorIndex = 27 'Change color to yellow
                sBody = sBody & vbNewLine & _
                    "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has almost expired. You have " & (365 - (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now))) & " days until it expires."
                
            ElseIf (DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) > 365 Then
                R.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Change color to red
                sOverdue = "overdue" 'Change message to overdue
                sBody = sBody & vbNewLine & _
                    "Your certification with the " & R.Offset((-(R.Row - 3)), 0) & " has expired. You are " & ((DateDiff("d", R.Value, Now)) - 365) & " days overdue for retraining."

            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'Create email
    Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
    With EItem
      .To = RName.Offset(0, 1)
      .Subject = "You're " & sOverdue & " for retraining and certification"
      .body = "Hello, " & RName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sBody
      .Display
    End With
   
    Set EApp = Nothing
    Set EItem = Nothing
        
Next RName

End Sub
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks, your loop was the key to this. Thank you. The only thing I had to do was end a stray If, and make it so that if sBody is blank then it won't send anything. This was great help, thank you very much!